# Brill bibliography templates

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Is anyone aware of any templates for what Brill calls the social sciences style? The reference in the text is handled very simply:  `(Author, Year:Page)` but in the bibliography the name of the author is on a separate line, the body of the citation(s) by that author indented below:

```
Smith, A
  - 1970 Bla bla bla
  - 1971 Bla bla bla
Fisher, B
  - 1980 Bla bla
```

I have looked through lists and lists of bibliography styles but found none that seemed to fit even loosely.

Comment: The `philosophy-modern `style from `biblatex-philosophy` seems to be close to what you describe. Do you want to have a dash before the year?

Comment: I can try to look how to patch this style to obtain the dash.

Comment: I looked again. Many thanks . Re dash, I got this wrong. I am sorry.